# a group specification must include an _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm having trouble performing a simple match for a group count.

He's forcing me to set a _id, but I'm already applying a matche

> (node:11004) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated.
>   Use createIndexes instead. O erro ----->  { MongoError: a group
>   specification must include an _id
>       at queryCallback (C:\stattrak\stattrak-rest\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:248:25)
>       at C:\stattrak\stattrak-rest\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:532:18
>       at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:70:11)   operationTime:    Timestamp {
>   *bsontype: 'Timestamp', low*: 4, high_: 1551646370 },   ok: 0,   errmsg: 'a group specification must include an _id',   code: 15955,
>   codeName: 'Location15955',   '$clusterTime':    { clusterTime:
>         Timestamp { *bsontype: 'Timestamp', low*: 4, high_: 1551646370 },
>        signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] } },   name: 'MongoError',   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

```
router.get('/update', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Historie.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $match: {
            user: req.userId
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
              _id: {
                user: req.userId
              },
              totalAmount: { $sum: "$points" },
              count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        }
      ]
   )
   console.log('--------> User: ', req.userId)
   console.log('-------------->', result)
   const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.userId, { $set: { points: result[0].totalAmount } })
    return res.send({ user });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('O erro -----> ', error)
    return res.status("400").send({ error: "Error at update user points" });
  }
})
```

Historie Model:

```
const HistorieSechema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  type: String,
  points: Number,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  validAt: Date,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Comment: `$group: { _id: "$user"` - See [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in the documentation